# Python - os.rename "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]"

Tags: python, file-rename, filenotfounderror

I'm trying to batch rename some photos and I wanna the second part only, e.g. renaming from `1234 - Photo_Name.jpg`  to `Photo_Name.jpg`.

This is my code:

```py
import os

folder = r"C:\Users\yousef\Downloads\Pictures\\"
files = os.listdir(folder)
for file_name in files:
    new_filename = file_name.split(' - ')[1]
    os.rename(file_name, new_filename)
```

But I get this **Error**

```
File "c:\Users\yousef\Downloads\code.py", line 7, in <module>
    os.rename(file_name, new_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '1234 - Photo_Name.jpg' -> 'Photo_Name.jpg'
```

Comment: What is the output of `os.getcwd()` (In other words, is the directory whose files you're trying to modify and the directory of the Python script the same?)

Comment: You need to add the directory prefix to the names.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `os.rename(file_name, new_filename)`, how do you expect it to decide where to look for `file_name`? You found that name by looking up the contents of the `r"C:\Users\yousef\Downloads\Pictures\\"` folder with `os.listdir`, but why should `os.rename` also know to look there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to rename the file in the current directory, not the folder you listed. Use `os.path.join()` to combine a directory with a filename.

```
import os

folder = r"C:\Users\yousef\Downloads\Pictures\\"
files = os.listdir(folder)
for file_name in files:
    new_filename = file_name.split(' - ')[1]
    os.rename(os.path.join(folder, file_name), os.path.join(folder, new_filename))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try prepending the full path of the folder to the source and destination file variables:

```py
import os

folder = r"C:\Users\yousef\Downloads\Pictures\\"
files = os.listdir(folder)
for file_name in files:
    new_filename = file_name.split(' - ')[1]
    os.rename(f"{folder}{file_name}", f"{folder}{new_filename}")
```